# Named Uniform Block binding point assignment

Tags: opengl, glsl

If I specify binding explicitly within a shader:

```c
layout (binding=0) uniform NamedUniformBlock {
   ...
};
```

...do I still need to call `glUniformBlockBinding()`?

Comment: No, `binding=0` does that already. You either set the binding point index directly from the shader **or** by a call to `glUniformBlockBinding`.